# How should I ask for the company/country/school's location?

Tags: grammar, questions

> ミイちゃんのかいしゃはどちらですか

The above is asking about the company (name of company).

How should I ask for the company's location?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are asking about.

Comment: Example question "トイレはどちらですか" mean "Where is the toilet" right? But "ミイちゃんのかいしゃはどちらですか" or "おくにはどちらですか"ask about name of company/country. So if I want to ask about the location of company/country, how can I ask?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Problem

> ミイちゃんのかいしゃはどちらですか

This actually could be used to ask for the location.
But as you mentioned, it could also mean "Which company do you belong (work) in?" So here are some alternatives:

---

## Alternatives

### ミイちゃんのかいしゃはどちらにありますか

*Where does ミイちゃんのかいしゃ exist?*

- This will **not** mean "Which company do you belong (work) in?"
- This could mean either "Where" (absolute) or "Which direction" (relative).
- This works for companies, countries, and schools.

---

### ミイちゃんのかいしゃのばしょはどちらですか

### ミイちゃんのかいしゃのばしょはどちらにありますか

*Where is the location of ミイちゃんのかいしゃ？*

- This will **not** mean "Which company do you belong (work) in?"
- This could mean either "Where" (absolute) or "Which direction" (relative).
- This works for companies, countries, and schools.

---

### ミイちゃんのかいしゃのじゅうしょはどちらですか

*Where is the address of ミイちゃんのかいしゃ？*

- This works for companies and schools, but **not** for countries.

---

## じゅうしょ and しょざいち

じゅうしょ means address, and it's a common word.
However actually, じゅうしょ is an address for people to live in, such as houses.
For company address, the correct term would be しょざいち.
But practically, most people just use じゅうしょ even for company addresses.

Comment: @Yuu I'm happy this helped, but I recommend you wait for other answers/comments from smarter people too.